# Infinite Scrolling with constant scroll bar height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working in infinite scrolling concept, unfortunately my project is stuck with a problem, my scenario is here

I am having a table containing 500 rows, initially first 100 rows will loaded and in that first 50 rows will displayed in my viewport, a dynamic content is added at the last of the rows, if my dynamic content reaches my viewport it will load another 100 rows.
The problem is, at inital stage the size of the scrollbar is very big and it looks like for only 100 rows.  I want the scrollbar to display in small size as it looks for 500 rows

Comment: would setting the initial height of the page to the height it has with 500 rows work?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I have already tried with setting the initial height for the entire page, but the height of the rows are not constant, it may differs for each records.

Comment: I have already worked the infinite scrolling concept, in such case if my last record reaches the view port it will load next 100 rows to the display.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force the display of the scrollbar, you have to change the size of the page.

You could init the height of the page with 5 times the actual height of the screen, but it will generate empty space after your page...

But It don't seems to be a good practice, if you look how google and facebook deals with infinite scrolling, you'll notice that the scrollbar just adapt with the size of the screen, so why don't you want to use the default behavior ?